# Creating a DetailView of a profile with a queryset of posts created by that user

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

I'm creating a twitter-like app and I'm stuck on creating a UserProfileView which is supposed to display a certain User's profile, along with a list of posts made by that user below. Though I can't really figure out a way to create a proper view for that.

I'm trying to use class based views for that, the one I'll be inheriting from is probably DetailView (for profile model) and something inside of that which retrieves a queryset of posts made by that user:

My profile model looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(
        default='assets/default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pictures')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default=user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profile", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=280)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='post_images/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Post by {self.author} on {self.date_posted} - {self.content[0:21]}'
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

I've tried creating this method:

```
class UserProfileView(DetailView):

    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(author=Profile.user)
        return context
```

But this one sadly doesn't work, raising an error of

```
"TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardOneToOneDescriptor object at 0x000001A5ACE80250>."
```

'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'id' is returned if I replace the filter argument with author=Profile.user.id

I'm not sure whether it's a problem with the way I filtered Posts, or how I used get_context_data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object is stored as `self.object`, so you can filter with:

```
class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(author_id=self.object.user_id)
        return context
```

An alternative might be to use a `ListView` for the `Post`s instead, to make use of Django's pagination:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView


class UserProfileView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(author__profile__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profile'] = get_object_or_404(Profile, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return context
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: So is the 'self' here in this method the view's Profile model?

Comment: @wisie: no the `DetailView` object, and it has a `.object` that is the `Profile` model object.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, this actually worked the way I wanted. Also do you think there is a way to implement pagination for that queryset? I'm using an infinite scrolling technique which works only for paginated ListViews, appending the current page with next `?page=X` requests. However since this isn't a ListView I can't add `paginate_by` to the class

Comment: @wisie: In that case I think you better make a `ListView` where you add the profile to the context, instead of a `DetailView` where you add the `Post`s to the context.

Comment: I use dynamic URLs for that, its page is on route `profile/<slug>` which is called by defining `model = Profile` inside the class, if I change that to post how do I pass that slug into the URL route?

Comment: @wisie: the `get_queryset` should return `Post.objects.filter(author__profile__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])` in the `get_context_data` you can use `get_object_or_404(Profile, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])`.

Comment: I'm really happy this somehow worked, however I have no idea how this is passed into urls.py. How does `get_queryset` allow me to pass the Profile slug into urls? I thought it's only used to get the queryset for the `for` loop in the HTML file?